# Good way to find the conditional probability involving order statistics

Tags: probability

Let $X_1,\cdots,X_{10}$ be iid from uniform distribution on $(0,1)$. We know that $Z = X_{(10)} - X_{(1)}$ has density $90 z^8 (1-z)$. Let $Y = \max( X_{(9)} - X_{(1)}, X_{(10)} - X_{(2)})$. What is $\mathbb{P}\left( Y \le y \mid Z = z\right)$?

I think there is some clever trick that I can use, but I can't think of any. I know that the joint distribution of $X_{(1)},\cdots,X_{(n)}$ is $n!$. So I tried to write
$$ P\left(Y\le y \mid Z=z\right) = P\left(X_{(10)} - y \le X_{(2)} <\cdots < X_{(9)} < X_{(1)} + y \mid Z=z\right)$$

I guess that conditioning on $X_{(10)} - X_{(1)} = z$, the probability is
$$P\left( X_{(1)} + z - y\le X_{(2)} \le \cdots \le X_{(9)} \le X_{(10)}-z+y\right)$$

after which I can compute it by a tedious integration. But what is the better way of doing this? My initial guess was that given the range, it suffices to let all the remaining $8$ points to be within the "middle part", so the answer is $\left(\frac{2y - z}{z}\right)^8$, but I don't know if it's correct or not.

What would be a good way to answer this problem?